# load dynamic properties of a component in qml file from another qml

Tags: c++, qml, qt-quick

I have two QML files in my project.

main.qml:

```
Window{
width: 800
height: 500
visible: true
id:mainWinenter 
Item {
       id: inlinecomponent
       Rectangle {
       id: display
       width: 50; height: 50
       color: "blue"
       }
   }
   MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent
       onClicked: {
           var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/Test.qml");
           var object  = component.createObject(inlinecomponent, {"x": 50, "y": 50});
       }
   }   }
```

and my Test.qml file:

```
Item{
id:mc

Rectangle{
    x: 0
    y: 0
    id: rec
    width: 150; height:75
    color: "grey"
    objectName: "recc"
    visible: true
}}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
 engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

 QQuickView view;
 view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Test.qml"));
 QQuickItem *object = view.rootObject();
 QObject *rect = object->findChild<QObject*>("recc");
 if (rect)
     rect->setProperty("color", "red");

 view.show();

return app.exec();}
```

In main.cpp I use setProperty function to change the color of rectangle in Test.qml file. The color changes when I load the file in new window but it doesn't change when it loads in main.qml file. How I can change it when it loads in main.qml?

My output contain two windows. One for main.qml and one for Test.qml.

[this is my main.qml output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLzTJ.jpg)

[this is my Test.qml output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KW84.jpg)

The color of the rectangle in my Test.qml window is red but it loads grey in my main.qml. I want to load it red in main file and I want to do this with my cpp code.

Comment: How did you change the color? May be you need  `component.createObject(inlinecomponent, {"x": 50, "y": 50, color: whatever})`?

Comment: @folibis I added my main.cpp file.I need to do this from my cpp code.

Comment: You have to clarify your question and add some appropriate code.

Comment: @folibis I tried so. :)

Comment: You haven't specified `objectName` in the `main.qml`. Anyways, when you've got things like`objectName` in QML or `findChild/setProperty` in the C++ code - it's not a good sign. You're not supposed to use that.

Comment: @Velkan Thanks a lot.